# Display only the first row per match

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have a table (AreaPartners), and I want to match only the first "Name" record in each group, order by "ID", grouped by "Area". So for the table below:

```
    Area    Name            ID
    AB      ISmith          748
    AB      AWood           750
    AB      HArcher         751
    AB      DMunslow        753
    AB      DCornelius      754
    BH      MLee            301
    BH      NMcClean        307
    BH      DMiles          309
    BH      LPayze          325
    BH      MPinnock        329
```

I'd want to return the results ISmith for AB and MLee for BH.

How do I go about doing this? I believe it's something to do with the Group By function, but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT yourTable.Area, yourTable.Name
FROM yourTable INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(Id) AS MinId
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY Area) M ON yourTable.Id = M.MinId
```

Comment: @aF. MS Access is not case-sensitive for object names in queries (i.e. `Id` is treated the same as `ID` or `id` or `iD`).

Comment: roger that, but it's always more "sensitive" to do it that way ;)

Comment: This was so nearly it - and the eventual solution used another table that I hadn't mentioned, so it wouldn't be fair to not choose it as the answer. This really helped, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update because of comment (There is no table variable and Partition over is not a MS access statement). You can also do it with an `IN` statement:

```
SELECT 
    yourTable.Area, 
    yourTable.Name
FROM yourTable 
WHERE yourTable.Id IN
(
    SELECT 
        MIN(tbl.Id) AS MinId
    FROM 
        yourTable as tbl
    GROUP BY 
        tbl.Area
)
```

In MSSQL you can write this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
    (
        Area VARCHAR(100),
        Name VARCHAR(100),
        ID INT
    )
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'AB','ISmith',748
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AB','AWood',750
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AB','HArcher',751
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AB','DMunslow',753
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AB','DCornelius',754
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BH','MLee',301
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BH','NMcClean',307
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BH','DMiles',309
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BH','LPayze',325
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BH','MPinnock',325
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.Area ORDER BY ID) AS iRank,
    tbl.ID,
    tbl.Area,
    tbl.Name
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.iRank=1
```

Comment: Does MS Access actually have CTEs and partitioning functions and table variables?

Comment: No, sorry about that. I thought that it was mssql :P.. But I think it would be a sweet select if it wore.

Comment: You should consider voluntarily deleting your answer then, or editing so it's applicable to MS Access.